# iCarousel error in xcode 9

Tags: swift, xcode, icarousel

I tried to implement iCarousel as per this tutorial: https://medium.com/@arb1nsnmgl/icarousel-walkthrough-swift-3-0-887554155242
but when trying to implement the @protocol it gives me 4 error messages:

1. Expected '{' in protocol type
2. Expected an attribute name
3. Protocol 'iCarouselDataSource' cannot be nested inside another declaration
4. Protocols do not allow generic parameters; use associated types instead

Currently the code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var carouselView: iCarousel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    //Testing
    @protocol iCarouselDataSource <NSObject>
    -(NSInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel;
    -(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(nullable UIView *)view;

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding it at wrong place so remove

```
@protocol iCarouselDataSource <NSObject>
-(NSInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel;
-(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index reusingView:(nullable UIView *)view;
```

From `viewDidLoad` method.

Above methods are delegate methods. And you need to add it as shown in tutorial.

Check point 11 for that.

Also confirm the delegates as shown in point number 8.